# Are there any built in LDAP functions to manipulate strings?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have a need to retrieve a value of a property in lower case, can LDAP have any built-ins to perform this? I know that I can do substrings and concatenations.

The need is for a software product we are using that i want a property retrieved in lower case (username property actually).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in an LDAP query.  You need to take the value returned and process it yourself.

As a subtle difference to your question. the underlying LDAP servers schema usually defines how queries work.  That is, you can have attributes who schema define their values as case sensitive or case insensitive.  Thus in a CE attribute, querying for JSmith will not work if the data is stored as jsmith.  Whereas it would work on a CI string.

Comment: Thanks mate, I was trying to get around a problem with a package where we can't alter which stores information against the username in it's database, unfortunately some of our users in LDAP have upper case names, this isn't a problem in itself but is when you want to query the user in the said package. I knew I could concatenate strings in LDAP so thought there might be a way to lower().

Answer (score 2):

A custom attribute with a specific matching rule can be defined to accomplish what you ask.